# Multi-threaded operations in parallel with timeout fails sometimes, difficult to debug

Tags: multithreading, networking, .net-core, system.reactive

This is the system I have: 
A dotnet application running on a server, needs to gather informations on devices on a very large network (1500-2000 devices).

Devices are of different type and manufacturer, some can be reached via Ssh, some via Snmp, but they are always in groups of the same type, so it's easy for me to interrogate the first and understand what type they are, and how to threat them.

This check needs to be done periodically, and as fast as possible, so I am multi-threading using System.Reactive.

Since I am looking for problems it may happen that a particular one doesn't respond, and I need a timeout to free that thread and get it working on a new one.

At the end I get a report for each device, divided in ones that are running fine, and those who are not, and possibly the error encountered.

This is the code I use:

```
Observable.Defer(source.ToObservable) 
                .ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
                .SelectMany(it => 
                    Observable.Start(() => DoNetworkCheck(it))
                        .Select(_ => true)
                        .Amb(Observable
                             .Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15))
                             .Select(_ => false)),

                    (it, result) => new { it, result })

                .Do (x => {

                        Interlocked.Increment(ref num);

                        var log = $"Checked: {x.it.type} - {x.it.ip}, Number {num} of {source.Count} in thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}";

                        if(x.result) {
                            log.toLine();
                        } 
                        else
                        {
                            (log + ", timeout: true").toErrLine();
                            exceptions.Enqueue(new Tuple<MacCpe, Exception>(x.it, new Exception($"Observable timeout, {observableTimespan} seconds")));
                        }
                },
                ex => { ex.StackTrace.toErrLine(); }, 
                () => onDone(routers.ToList(), exceptions.ToList())).Wait();
```

I have it working and it works for almost all devices, but I have some strange cases that I can't figure out.

Every time, out of 2000 network devices, 20-25 will go timeout, they are always different, and if I run the program only on those 20-25 they will respond correctly. 
So I don't think it is a problem with the devices, but the program.
When I am looking at the thread visualisation I see certain threads are stuck, and go in timeout, but I can't figure out why.

It's almost like there is a 1% probability the thread will deadlock on something...?

How can I know what's wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm wary of the `.Wait()` - why not replace the `Do`/`Wait` combo with a `Subscribe`?

Comment: Also the `.ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)` is probably in the wrong place. The subsequent `SelectMany` will likely change the scheduler because of both the `Start` and the `Amb`. Try putting it just before the `Do` (or `Subscribe`).

Comment: I'm using the Do/Wait because otherwise with subscribe, the program will just go ahead and terminate before it can finish the task.

Comment: Also trying to put the .ObserveOn after SelectMany, everything happens on one thread sequentially.

Comment: "everything happens on one thread sequentially" - as opposed to "everything happens on multiple threads sequentially" in your code originally. So what was the point of the `ObserveOn` in your code then?

Comment: No point, I should have said before that I don't have a lot of practice with System.Reactive

Comment: Fair enough. You know that everything happens sequentially per subscription?

Comment: Yes they pass sequentially through onNext. What is your advice for parallelizing the work in a thread pool? .Zip? Also do you think this configuration has anything to do with the fact that some threads get stuck?

Comment: The way you're doing it looks good. I'd have to see a [mcve] to get any more idea.

Comment: That's difficult to achieve, I'm testing things in production directly with a separate database, cause it's difficult to have mock devices to test on...

Comment: Yet that's where you're at. The code you've posted doesn't explain your issue.

Comment: With 2000 connections, and assuming you are using low level sockets. Are you correctly disposing your sockets? You might be exhausting your OS socket limit. If so, the timeout is on the creation of the sockets. It is also possible that your socket creation is throttled by the OS (see: https://superuser.com/questions/4582/is-there-a-half-open-tcp-connection-limit-in-win-7). Try also to slow down the creation of connections.

Comment: This might be a plausible, at the beginning I was using wrapper libraries like: https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET, then I was afraid of them being outdated, and maybe not working right on linux, so now I am building the command as a string to terminal command. Both approaches had the mentioned problems. Is there a way to check on the sockets at debug time?